# Redirects are Overriding each other

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect a bunch of uploads from our old website that no longer exist. I have one specific section I wanted to route to a resources page, but the rest will simply redirect to the home page.

`/uploads*`: redirects to homepage

`/uploads/resources*`: redirects to resources

The first redirect is overruling the second, and everything in /uploads is redirecting to the home page. Is there a way to make a special exception for this one folder? Through using a regex or something else?

Comment: How are you doing the redirects?  Through `.htaccess`?  If so, can you share your code?

Answer (score 4):

Try **swapping the order of your Routes** (drag and drop), so that specific resources are routed first and the homepage fallback is positioned second.

Routes are applied in the order the appear in **Settings** > **Routes** i.e. If a route criteria is matched then Craft doesn't seem to try the rest.

More info here: https://craftcms.com/docs/routing just in case you haven't seen it already.

Let us know if that helps.